# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'domain.com/wsdl' : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap

I am switching from one virtual server to another and having problems.

New server is running PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze1. Old is PHP Version 5.2.17.

Simple SOAP script

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);
```

gives error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'domain.com/wsdl' : failed to load external entity
```

Even trying file_get_contents fails on the new server but works on the old server.

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.uk/");
```

I've tried to match the php.ini files. allow_url_fopen = On is enabled, as is SOAP and cURL.

Any advice would be really helpful.

Thanks you.

Comment: First thing I did was echo phpinfo() for both. There is no obvious discrepency. allow_url_fopen is enabled for both.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine may not have acces to the internet.
Try next command in a console :

```
telnet www.google.co.uk 80
```

to know if your server can connect to the internet on port 80 (http).
If no, ask your sysadmin or network manager, it don't come from apache configuration.